# Composing HQL statement

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

Hi,
I have database Staff with 3 tables:

```
mysql> describe person;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| person_id  | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| date       | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| first_name | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| last_name  | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| position   | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| salary     | double       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

mysql> describe department;
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| department_id | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| dept_name     | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

mysql> describe department_person;
+---------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| department_id | bigint(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| person_id     | bigint(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+---------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

And I want to compose HQL statement for getting data from **department.dept_name** using **person.lastName**. I've used the following code to extract this data but without luck:

```
public List<Person> findByDepartment(){
        Session session =
                HiberUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        List<Person> result = session.createQuery("select d.dept_name from Person p " +
            "join p.Department d where p.id = 'Andreas'").list();
        for(Person a : result) {
            Hibernate.initialize(a.getDepartmentList());
        }
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        return result;

    }
```

Can you help please in composing HQL query correctly?

**UPD**

**Person.java**

```
**@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "department_person", joinColumns = { 
        @JoinColumn(name = "person_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, 
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "department_id", 
                nullable = false, updatable = false) })
private Set<Department> departmentList = new HashSet<Department>();**
```

**Department.java**

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "department_person", joinColumns = { 
            @JoinColumn(name = "department_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, 
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "person_id", 
                    nullable = false, updatable = false) })
    private Set<Person> personList;
```

Comment: Are your entities mapped with OneToMany , OneTo... relations ?

Comment: Mapped with ManyToMany, I've updated post with code snippets

Comment: One last question you want the list of person using department name (as your method name would suggest) or the department name for one person

Comment: You were given good help on your last question, which is pretty much exactly the same as this one. Voting to close as duplicate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting data from database using HQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16023703/getting-data-from-database-using-hql)

Comment: Yes, I want the list of person using department name.

Comment: Perception, that question was not connected with ManyToMany relation. It was another relation. I didn't find useful example of ManyToMany extracting approach using HQL that's why I'm asking help in composing this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query should work :

```
Query query = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createQuery("SELECT d.personList FROM Department d WHERE d.departmentName = :departmentName");
query.setParameter("departmentName", departmentName);
List<Person> resultList = query.getResultList();
```

Thanks to hibernate you don't need to care about the join table.
Let me know if it does not work

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your mapping is wrong. You have a many to many bidirectional association here, so one of the side must be the owner, and define the mapping using @JoinTable, and the other side must be the inverse side, and use the mappedBy attribute. If you want the person to be the owner, the mapping should thus be:

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "department_person", 
           joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "person_id") }, 
           inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "department_id") })
private Set<Department> departmentList = new HashSet<Department>();

...

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "departmentList")
private Set<Person> personList;
```

Note that LAZY is the default for toMany associations, and that cascade = ALL doesn't make much sense for many to many associations.

Then you must understand that HQL uses entity and attribute names, and not table and column names. You must also realize that if you select department names, you'll get a list of department names, and not a list of persons.

So, if you want to get the list of persons for a given depertment name, you should use

```
select distinct p from Person p
join p.departmentList d 
where d.name = :departmentName
```

Comment: JB Nizet, thank you for your explanation, I will come back to it to uderstand at free time.